# Add a tag in excel file by using excel macro save as a new excel file

Tags: python, excel, vba

I would like to add a tag in excel file by using excel macro save as a new excel file.
How to make this macro program or which command that can support to add a tags.

[image]

Comment: Look into document properties :)

Comment: Here's the closest I could find on a few searches - https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1118708/Bit-Application-Cannot-Use-DSOfile - in short, it's not exactly a simple thing, and may involve installing something to get it to work in VBA.